# Joomla URL redirect

Tags: php, joomla, metadata, joomla1.5, meta

I've got a question here about joomla redirection. . I got a Joomla site that has a bug.
Each time i visit the site, it redirects to other site. . but when i put `www.site.com/index.php`, it's ok.  i already look on the >ndex.html##  there's a meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://redirectto.com/">
```

but if i removed or change the meta, the site got a error. .

anyone can helpe about this problem??

Comment: what error message do you get when you delete this line?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla does not normally use index.html *anywhere* - though there is such a file in almost every folder, it's supposed to be empty for security reasons.  I can't say for sure if you've installed something that puts this code in an index.html for a reason, but I've never seen anything like that before.

Re-reading, it looks like your apache config is defaulting to index.html, when it should be defaulting to index.php.  Check your apache config, or put an htaccess file in your joomla folder to do this, or joomla isn't likely to work properly anyways - it needs to default to index.php